# Ruby script can't find CSV file

Tags: ruby

I have a simple crawler written in Ruby that should crawl specific sites and save data into a CSV file, but, when running it from the Windows command line I get this error:

```
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/csv.rb:1282:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - csv/boxers.csv (Errno::ENOENT)
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/csv.rb:1282:in `open'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/csv.rb:1282:in `open'
    from boxers.rb:18:in `<main>'
```

This is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'csv'
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new{ |agent| agent.history.max_size=0 }
agent.user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0'

base = "http://baseurl.com/"

division = ARGV[0]

search_url = "http://baseurl.com/ratings.php?sex=M&division=#{division}&pageID="

path='//*[@id="mainContent"]/table/tr[position()>2]'

boxers = CSV.open("csv/file.csv","w")

url = search_url+"1"

begin
  page = agent.get(url)
rescue
  print "  -> error, retrying\n"
  retry
end


end

boxers.close
```

Comment: See "[mcve]". Well, we can't help very well because we don't have visibility into your disk and you didn't tell us enough. Have you checked to see if the "csv" directory exists? Do you have permissions to write and create files in that directory? Reduce your code in the question to the bare minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem. Odds are good that means it's only the `open` statement.

Comment: As written, the code _should_ create "file.csv" in the "csv" sub-directory of the local directory. If "csv" doesn't exist it won't be created and the code will fail with a message like you're getting. I'd recommend using the block form of `open` so that it'll automatically close the file after the block exits. And, as displayed, the code will fail because there is an extra trailing `end` statement. Fix that as it's a syntax error and is cause for closing the question.

Comment: Fixed the problem, there was just inattention of mine (folder that should be called csv was called cvs). Thanks for your replies.